# Restos de datos no convertidos cuando se despojan de las cosas innecesarias

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timestamp, dash

Intento extraer las fechas de un `DatePickerRange` de la libreria `dash_core_components` pero, despues de despojar de las cosas innecesarisas me dice el compilador que hay restos que no puede utilizar:

```
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_core_components as dcc
import datetime as dt

import pickle

from ..server import app

@app.callback(
    # Output('output-container-button', 'children'),
    Output('articles', 'children'),
    [Input('button', 'n_clicks'), 
    Input('my-date-picker-range', 'start_date_value'),
    Input('my-date-picker-range', 'end_date_value')],
    [State('input-box', 'value')])
def update_search(n_clicks, value, start_date_value, end_date_value):
    f = pickle.load(open("dashboard/data-mm/google-nlu-khazaradze.p", "rb"))
    # let's filter f according to value
    print(start_date_value)
    start_date = dt.datetime.strptime(start_date_value.split(' ')[0], '%Y-%m-%d')
    end_date = dt.datetime.strptime(end_date_value.split(' ')[0], '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Pero me contesta el compilador:

```
File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\richmond2\dashboard\callbacks\search.py", line 20, in update_search
start_date = dt.datetime.strptime(start_date_value.split(' ')[0], '%Y-%m-%d')
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\_strptime.py", line 577, in _strptime_datetime
tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\_strptime.py", line 362, in _strptime
data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains: T11:55:55.226148
```

Aqui esta lo que contiene `start_date_value` :

```
2020-01-28T11:55:55.226148
```

Que es lo mismo que `start_date.split(' ')[0]`

Answer (score 1):

El error se debe a que el formato que pasas a `strptime` no coincide con la fecha. Espera encontrar `%Y-%m-%d`, es decir `"2020-01-28"`
pero tu fecha contiene  también la hora (`2020-01-28T11:55:55.226148`) que queda sin parsear, por eso el error ("unconverted data remains"). No hay forma de hacer que `strptime` ignore parte de la entrada y que no trate de parsearla.

El formato correcto es:

```
'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'
```

Un ejemplo reproducible basado en tu código:

```
import datetime as dt



start_date_value = "2020-01-28T11:55:55.226148 algo"
start_date = dt.datetime.strptime(start_date_value.split(' ')[0], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Answer (score 0):

Fue seguro que la fecha esperaba encontrar una cosa como `%Y-%m-%d`, es decir "2020-01-28" pero hasta que la fecha contiene también la hora (`2020-01-28T11:55:55.226148`) he separado sobre el `T`:

```
        end_date = dt.datetime.strptime(end_date.split('T')[0], '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Y funciona tambien